# The buttons of cookieconsent package not work in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, cookies, cookieconsent

I have a front in Vue.

I've added the package cookieconsent:

```js
import cookieconsent from "cookieconsent";

Vue.use(cookieconsent);
```

In App.vue I initialise it:

```js
created() {
    this.cookiesConsentInitialise();
  },

methods: {
    cookiesConsentInitialise() {
       window.cookieconsent.initialise({
        //...
        //settings
        //...
      });
    }
}
```

The cookie notification is displayed perfectly, but the accept and decline buttons not perform any action, stays on the screen all the time.

I have followed Osano's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [vue-cookie-law](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookie-law) npm package as it is optimised for vue projects and is popular enough.

There is good documentation and it is pretty customisable.